# Django - What kind of problems will I have when use this schema/model with ModelForms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm developing a model for a new django app. The model is a little bit complex and as new to Django I need to know what kind of problems I will face with this kind of schema/model when dealing with the ModelForm. To this schema work correctly I must to add some additional code, the schema is not CRUD ready.

The schema/model:

[image: django schema/model]

- This schema/model is what a Django model should look like in terms of design?
- I will be able to add business logic to the ModelForm?

Give me some clues on what problems I will be facing with this kind of model and ModelForms.

Best Regards,

Comment: I don't see any problems in converting this schema in django models

Comment: The problem is not converting. The problem is that this schema is not CRUD ready. I must to add some business logic code. I need to know if it is possible to use not ready CRUD models with ModelForms?

Comment: I think you need [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)

Answer (score 0):

I see you have many models which help you to categorize or define the instance type. This is not much of django approach instead of using separate models. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
BYCYCLE_AD_TYPE = (
  (db_value_1, "Show_value"),
  (db_value_1, "Show_value"),
  (db_value_2, "Show_value"),
)

class BicycleAd(models.Model):
  ad_type = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  ...Your other fields...
```